# Translation of the Word Συντέλεια

Tags: greek, christianity, new-testament

The ancient text of Matthew 24:3 reads:

“Καθημένου δὲ αὐτοῦ ἐπὶ τοῦ ὄρους τῶν ἐλαιῶν προσῆλθον αὐτῷ οἱ μαθηταὶ κατ᾽ ἰδίαν λέγοντες· εἰπὲ ἡμῖν, πότε ταῦτα ἔσται καὶ τί τὸ σημεῖον τῆς σῆς παρουσίας καὶ **συντελείας** τοῦ αἰῶνος.”

One modern Greek Bible translation has rendered the verse in the following way:

“Ενώ καθόταν στο Όρος των Ελαιών, οι μαθητές τον πλησίασαν ιδιαιτέρως, λέγοντας: «Πες μας, πότε θα γίνουν αυτά, και ποιο θα είναι το σημείο της παρουσίας σου και της **τελικής περιόδου** του συστήματος πραγμάτων.»”

Is the modern translation correct when it renders the word συντέλεια with the phrase “final period” (τελική περίοδος)?

Answer (score 2):

Good question!

*Syntéleia* is formed from the verb *syn-teléō*, which originally meant "to complete something". It was the verb for placing the final stone on a building, making the finishing touches on an artwork, or paying off the last part of a loan.

Because of this last meaning, it also started to mean "to contribute to a fund", even if you weren't the one to "finish" it. So if you look up *syntéleia* in a dictionary, the first meaning you'll find is "a tax to be paid". And then the verb also started to mean "to be in a certain tax bracket", so the second meaning you'll find for *syntéleia* is "tax bracket".

But in this case, we're interested in the original meaning: "completion". *Syntéleia* is the moment of completion when everything finally falls into place. In the Vulgate it's rendered as *consummātio*, "consummation", which is a very literal translation (con~syn, summa~télos).

P.S. You'll notice the same root in *syn**tél**eia* and the modern ***tel***ikěs: the word *télos* originally meant "end", though its meaning weakened a lot over time.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to me that the translation of the word συντέλεια as “final period” (τελική περίοδος) is not correct at Mt 24:3, because the context in Matthew chapter 24 speaks about Christ’s coming and the end (τέλος, mentioned at Mt 24:14), which are short events rather than long periods of time.